# How to make UFW work with firewalld on CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, ufw, firewalld

I've installed UFW on a fresh CentOS 7 installation, but it doesn't open the ports. I'm configuring UFW as I would on a Debian system:

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow http
```

The I check what is allowed:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
```

Returns:

```
services: ssh dhcpv6-client
```

Port scan shows only port 22 and 53 are open.

When I issue the following, port 80 is accessible:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=http
```

I prefer UFW as it allows me to type shorter commands and is uncomplicated (as the name suggests).

Any reason why it doesn't work or why I should not use it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable firewalld and reboot: `service firewalld stop ; systemctl disable firewalld.service ; service firewalld status`